# How to delete lists that contain sublists of different sizes?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I hope to have your help, if I have

```
listp = Permutations[Range[7]];
```

With the following functions, I delete the lists that contain `{7,2}` and `{2,7}` of the variable `listp`

```
filtro[num_List]:=If[Position[num,7]==Position[num,2]+1,False,True];
sfir[num_List]:=If[Position[num,7]==Position[num,2]-1,False,True];
```

For example in `listp` is the permutation `{1,4,2,7,6,3,5}`, which should be deleted from `listp`, since it contains `{2,7}`, also permutation `{5,1,6,4 , 3,2,7}` should be deleted from `listp` for the same reason. To make all permutations like those mentioned above be removed from `listp` I do the following:

```
ek = Select[listp, filtro];
{Length[listp], Length[ek]}
```

As you can see 720 permutations of listp have been eliminated, I have only used {2,7} as a criterion, now if I use {7,2} let's see how many permutations are eliminated

```
do = Select[ek, sfir];
{Length[listp], Length[ek], Length[do]}
```

You will have already noticed that 720 permutations were erased, in total 1440 permutations of `listp` have been eliminated.

What I did in the previous section was simply delete all the permutations of `{2,7}` which are

```
Permutations[{2,7}]
```

The problem is that for each permutation I had to build a function, besides I want to erase other permutations, which I enlist so that you know what they are.

```
Permutations[{1,3,5}];
Permutations[{2,4,6,7}];
```

If I have counted correctly, I would have to do 30 functions to erase all the permutations that I want from `listp`. I would like to ask you to please help me carry out this `listp` debugging, since I thought about using the `DeleteCases` command but I did not know how to assign the permutations that I want to delete within that command, maybe you know an alternative method to achieve my goal. Any help is welcome since I am stuck in this part. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think [`OrderlessPatternSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderlessPatternSequence.html) is the missing piece. For example,

```
DeleteCases[listp, {___, OrderlessPatternSequence[2, 7], ___}]
```

will delete any list inside `listp` that contains the sequence `2,7` or `7,2`.

If there are other sequences to be deleted you could make a composite pattern with

```
patt = Alternatives[
   OrderlessPatternSequence[2, 7],
   OrderlessPatternSequence[1, 3, 5],
   OrderlessPatternSequence[2, 4, 6, 7]
   ];
```

and

```
DeleteCases[listp, {___, patt, ___}]
```

will delete any list containing these orderless patterns.

If you are using a version prior to 10.1 then `OrderlessPatternSequence` is not defined, and you can implement it yourself as

```
OrderlessPatternSequence[args___] := 
 Alternatives @@ PatternSequence @@@ Permutations@{args}
```

Comment: First of all an apology for thanking you so far, the solution that you shared with me works wonderfully, I have tried it online and I get what I was looking for, thanks for your help. I do not know if you have any solution that works in MMA version 10.0, since in that version there is no command OrderlessPatternSequence, that would be extra because I have that version on desktop, thank you again

Comment: No need to apologize at all.  See the edit for an alternative definition.

Answer (score 2):

Sequence functions are much slower than Jason's answer (0.322 vs
0.014 sec for `n = 7`, but might be useful for short lists in some
cases.

```
n = 4;

list = Permutations[Range @ n];
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Cases[#, {Repeated[_, {n}]}, -1]& @
 Map[SequenceSplit[#, {2, 4} | {4, 2}] &] @ list
```

{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3, 4}, {2, 1, 4, 3}, {2, 3, 1,
4}, {2, 3, 4, 1}, {3, 2, 1, 4}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 1,
3, 2}, {4, 3, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 2, 1}}

Using `SequenceCases` (new in 10.1)

```
Extract[list, Position[SequenceCases[#, {2, 4} | {4, 2}] & /@ list, {}]]
```

(* same result *)

Answer (score 2):

```
list = Permutations[Range[4]];
```

Grabbing the @eldo's list and using `SequencePosition`:

```
Pick[list, Length@SequencePosition[#, {2, 4} | {4, 2}] === 0 & /@ list]

  (*{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3, 4}, {2, 1, 4, 3},
     {2, 3, 1,4}, {2, 3, 4, 1} {3, 2, 1, 4}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, 
     {4, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 1, 3, 2}, {4, 3, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 2, 1}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Also:

```
n = 4; list = Permutations[Range @ n];
seq = {2, 4};
```

Using `LongestCommonSubsequence`

```
Cases[x_ /; (LongestCommonSubsequence[x, #] != # & /@ And @@ Permutations@seq)]@list
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3, 4}, {2, 1, 4, 3}, {2, 3, 1,
> 4}, {2, 3, 4, 1}, {3, 2, 1, 4}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 1,
> 3, 2}, {4, 3, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 2, 1}}

In terms of performance, for the problem at hand, generating the permutations to be excluded and removing them from the whole list afterwards, seems to run even faster.

```
subsetPermutations[n_][seq_List] := 
   Flatten /@ Permutations[{seq, Splice@Complement[Range@n, seq]}]

Complement[Permutations[Range@n], Flatten[subsetPermutations[n] /@ Permutations[seq], 1]]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3, 4}, {2, 1, 4, 3}, {2, 3, 1,
> 4}, {2, 3, 4, 1}, {3, 2, 1, 4}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 1,
> 3, 2}, {4, 3, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 2, 1}}